# How to slide out a textbox from a link hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div id="ctl00_nmSearch" class="searchBox" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, &#39;HiddenSearchNM&#39;)">

                                <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Search WESTMED" id="searchB" class="styledTB searchB floatLeft" />
                                <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" onclick="SearchNMClick();" title="Search" class="styledBtnSearch searchAnchor floatLeft defaultLinks"><img src="theImages/searchWhite.png" alt="Search" title="Search" class="searchImg" /></a>
                                <input type="image" name="ctl00$HiddenSearchNM" id="HiddenSearchNM" class="hideContent" src="" />

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.searchBox
{
    background: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}
.styledTB {
    padding-left: 5px;
    background: #E8E8E8;
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    right: 35px;
    box-shadow:
        0px 5px #BBB,
        0px 8px 10px rgba(148, 148, 148, 0.5);
}
.searchB
{
    height: 30px;
    width: 80%;
}
.floatLeft {
    float: left;
}
.styledBtnSearch
{
    border: 0;
    background: #0071C7;
    display: block;
    box-shadow:
        0px 5px #014477,
        0px 8px 10px rgba(148, 148, 148, 0.5);
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.searchAnchor
{
    width: 8%;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oLfLjyuu/1/

How can I use JQuery so when the user hover over the blue `a` the textbox slides out? I would like it to hide initially.

Comment: Does this require jQuery? because it can be done in CSS.

Comment: How do in CSS? Thanks/.

Answer (score 1):

I have used jquery mouseover and focusout events, with the jquery ui slide effect.

```
$('.search-module').mouseover(function() {
  $('#searchB').slideDown();
});

$('.search-module').focusout(function() {
  $('#searchB').slideUp();
});
```

I think this is what you meant:

http://jsfiddle.net/q90b2nss/

I must warn you though you are using some bad practices, like 'a' element has two class attributes, and embedding js behavior inside HTML. If it's just for the the jsfiddle that's okay, but otherwise it can get tough maintaining a site this way.

Edit: after playing with it, I realize you would want the focusout instead of mouseleave event

Comment: even for jsfiddle it's bad practice

Answer (score 0):

```
.styledBtnSearch:hover+input {
    display:block
}

.hideContent {
    display: none
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oLfLjyuu/3/

this will just hide and show on hover, in case you want it not to collapse you have to put that on parent div, I'm not sure can you modify the html?
in case you actually want a slide option please comment (you can use transition for that)

Comment: I don't think he means the submit button, but rather the big grey textbox on the left

Comment: I wanted something like the apple website.